# CU October 2011 Invalid object name 'Webs'

Tags: upgrade, content-database, cumulative-update

I've runed the CU October 2011 and Sharepoint Configuration Wizard failed after executing, however the farm build version changed to: 14.0.6112.5000 as expected.
In ULS i've seen error: **Invalid name 'Webs'**
I run powershell script:

```
PS C:\Users\christof> Test-SPContentDatabase -Name WSS_Content -WebApplication http://coffee
```

and result was:

> Test-SPContentDatabase : Invalid object name 'Webs'.
>   At line:1 char:23
>   + Test-SPContentDatabase <<<<  -Name WSS_Content -WebApplication http://coffee
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...ContentDatabase:
>      SPCmdletCheckContentDatabase) [Test-SPContentDatabase], SqlException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletCheckCon
>      tentDatabase
>   Blockquote

Now my web is down and I can not rollback it - what I can do? Of course I have restared the machine, iisresets etc and also **Upgrade-SPContentDatabase** also gives same error as Test-SPContentDatabase.

Comment: Where you able to figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Sounds like your content database has melted. Hope you have backups!

Answer (score 1):

sometimes if you re-intall the CU it fixes the issue. As a side note, always have a snapshot before you apply any patches

Comment: Just keep in mind that virtual machine snapshots are not supported with SharePoint and in a multi-server farm, will not lead you back to a consistent environment.

Comment: That is alarming for me as i always suggested my clients to take a snapshot of their VMs (WFE's and APP servers) before doing anything to the farm. Can you please suggest me a MSFT  reference on this?